# Tensorflow Object Detection API - GitHub

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-datasets, object-detection-api

I am a beginner with TF and I am trying to running some Tensorflow Object Detection API with:

- GeForce 2GB-MX150
- 16GB RAM
- I7 8550U

I getting the following error when it starts training and I can't figure out what's wrong.
I have tried to change some parameters like batch size multiple times but it stil getting the some error.

In [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cHO4v.png) you can see the total and available memory that the computer has.

I'll grateful for you help me.

```
    ResourceExhaustedError (see above for traceback): OOM when allocating tensor with shape[1,1024,52,38] and type float on /job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0 by allocator GPU_0_bfc      [[Node: FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_20/bottleneck_v1/conv3/Conv2D
= Conv2D[T=DT_FLOAT, data_format="NCHW", dilations=[1, 1, 1, 1], padding="SAME", strides=[1, 1, 1, 1], use_cudnn_on_gpu=true,
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0"](FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_20/bottleneck_v1/conv2/Relu, FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_20/bottleneck_v1/conv3/weights/read/_2629)]] Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.

     [[Node: gradients/FirstStageFeatureExtractor/resnet_v1_101/resnet_v1_101/block3/unit_18/bottleneck_v1/conv3/Conv2D_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1/_3229
= _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:GPU:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_6894_...pendency_1", tensor_type=DT_FLOAT,
_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"]()]] Hint: If you want to see a list of allocated tensors when OOM happens, add report_tensor_allocations_upon_oom to RunOptions for current allocation info.
```

Answer (score 0):

2 GB of GPU memory on your is far too little for a huge model like ResNet-101.

Comment: Yeah Professor you are righ.

Comment: I already solved the problem, what I did was to reduce the size of images. but I could have problems with the object detection when changing the size of imanges?

Comment: Yes, increasing input image size normally means that you need more memory for activations as well.